# How to securely enable a feature after validating in-app purchase

Tags: ios, security, in-app-purchase

I'm working on an iOS app, but if there is an answer here, it may apply to other platforms as well.

There are basically two ways to validate an in-app purchase: locally and server-side. The server side method is [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store). (I can't find the docs for the local method at the moment.)

Let's say I validate the purchase server-side. My question is about what happens after that, to enable the purchased feature(s). I don't see documentation on this. Am I missing it?

I imagine two or three steps:

1. Server sends an HTTPS response to the iOS app, saying "yes, you made X purchase".
2. The app flips some boolean variable in memory to enable the purchased features.
3. [Maybe] The app saves this state to local storage so that it doesn't need to revalidate the receipt via the internet every time it launches.

All of these steps seem vulnerable to attack on a hacked/jailbroken client device. Obviously there are tradeoffs between the difficulty of hacking and the cost of the in-app purchase and potential lost revenue. I'm thinking about the case where the app is more expensive or popular and there may be incentive to hack it.

Example possible vulnerabilities: (again, all of these probably require a helpful - to the hacker - OS kernel)

- a real server response could be sniffed and inspected and then faked for other users
- the app's memory could be inspected and the boolean variable flipped
- if the state is saved (for example, in a file, or in the user defaults key-value store) that state could be altered

So, are there some techniques to mitigate or prevent these hacks? Or do companies simply accept that a determined hacker can steal software, and take it as part of the cost of doing business?

Comment: All these vulnerabilities can only happen on jailbroken device. Why do you care about these kind of users? I think implementing such high level of security is redundant. Regarding, your question: yes, most apps just save boolean value to local storage after successful purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there is a "correct" answer here since you outlined it pretty well:

> Obviously there are tradeoffs between the difficulty of hacking and the cost of the in-app purchase and potential lost revenue.

If there was an official way of handling this then it does just become a target for hacking.

Most apps I've seen (even large ones) are keeping data in local storage to determine purchase status. But... you can keep this data on a short cache and refresh it in the background every 5 min or so. That way a hacker would need to overwrite it every 5min which makes normal usage pretty impractical.

Unless you have a high cost of supporting users (e.g. Spotify paying licensing costs) then there's probably better areas to invest in than this.